# term vs clause in the context of normal forms

Tags: terminology, normal-forms

In the context of disjunctive normal forms, which terminology do you use for the conjunction of atoms? E.g., for the disjunctive normal form $(x₁ ∧ ¬x₂ ∧ x₃) ∨ (¬x₁ ∧ x₂ ∧ x₃)$, how are the constituents "$x₁ ∧ ¬x₂ ∧ x₃$" and "$¬x₁ ∧ x₂ ∧ x₃$" called? Terms or clauses? I saw boths variants as well as "disjunctive clauses", and I wonder which variant is right.

There are lots of non-native English computer scientists around, so please reply only if you are an established computer scientist who actually taught this and have an excellent command of English.

Answer (score 1):

They're often called a "clause", "conjunctive clause", or sometimes a "conjunction" (if it is clear from context what that is referring to).

See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form.